# Kubernetes in Vsphere Virtual machines

Tags: kubernetes

Dears,
Sorry may be a basic question for some of you. If i have a Vsphere Environment and i am allowed to access only 2 Virtual machines inside them. Can I set kubernetes cluster with 1 VM as master and 1 VM as Minion without interacting with the hypervisor or the Vsphere center ? 
In this case what are the requirements 
I already set up an environment in my Laptop but i should define a host only network in Virtualbox and define the machines also for the host ? should that be the same in case of Vsphere ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some requirements for Kubernetes cluster. According to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) it is necessary to have:

> - One or more machines running one of:
>
>   - Ubuntu 16.04+
>   - Debian 9
>   - CentOS 7
>   - RHEL 7
>   - Fedora 25/26 (best-effort)
>   - HypriotOS v1.0.1+
>   - Container Linux (tested with 1800.6.0)
> - 2 GB or more of RAM per machine (any less will leave little room for your apps)
> - 2 CPUs or more
> - Full network connectivity between all machines in the cluster (public or private network is fine)
> - Unique hostname, MAC address, and product_uuid for every node. See here for more details.
> - Certain ports are open on your machines. See here for more details.
> - Swap disabled. You MUST disable swap in order for the kubelet to work properly.

Also, IP subnets for Services and for Pods must not interfere with IP subnets in the same VPC.

To set up Kubernetes cluster it is enough to have SSH access to VMs. Additional network interfaces are not required.

If you already have VMs, the most convenient tool for cluster creation is `kubeadm`. Please, consider reading the following part of official documentation:

- [Creating a single master cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)